# compare two file keys and update the value of file2 with corresponding key in file1

Tags: file, join, awk, merge, compare

I want to compare two files. file1 having below content,

```
 File1:
   key1=value1
   key2=value2
   key3=value3
   key4=value4
   key5=value5
```

my file2 having below content

```
 File2:
   key2=value2.2
   key3=value3.3
```

now i want to compare both key value pair and update the value of matched key in file2 to file1 and also keep the remaining key value in file1

my expected file below:

```
 File3:
   key1=value1
   key2=value2.2
   key3=value3.3
   key4=value4
   key5=value5
```

suggest any command or shell scripts?

Answer (score 0):

A possible way:

```
join -t = -a 1 file1 file2 | sed 's/=.*=/=/'
```

the `-a 1` parameter forces to print the line from file 1 if the key doesn't exist in file2.

Note that to use the `join` command, the two files must be previously sorted. If they aren't, you can write this:

```
join -t = -a 1 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | sed 's/=.*=/=/'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem newfile.sh

In newfile.sh contain

```
   ##############file1 value#################
   var1=`cat /path/to/file1.txt | grep -i "key2" | cut -d '=' -f2`
   var2=`cat /path/to/file1.txt | grep -i "key3" | cut -d '=' -f2`
   ###############file2 value###################
   var11=`cat /path/to/file2.txt | grep -i "key2" | cut -d '=' -f2`
   var22=`cat /path/to/file2.txt | grep -i "key3" | cut -d '=' -f2`
   ###############################################
   sed -i "s~$var1~$var11~g; s~$var2~$var22~g" /path/to/file1.txt
```